# Getting items from list with Knockout

Tags: rest, knockoutjs, databind

I'm trying to get items from a list usin REST and knockout and this is my code

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insightViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.insights = ko.observableArray([]);

self.GetInsights = function () {
$.ajax({
   url: "http://demo/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('news')/items",
  type: "GET",
       headers: {
       "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
       },
       success: function (data) {
       alert("Get data-"+data.d.results);
       self.insights.push(data.d.results);
       },
         error: function (error) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
     });
   }
      self. GetInsights();
   }


$(document).ready(function () {
 insightModel = new insightViewModel();
var insightDiv = document.getElementById("divDatabinding");
insightViewModel();
});
//
</script>

<body>
 <div id="divDatabinding"> 
   <table >
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
       <tbody data-bind="foreach:insights">
        <tr>                       
         <td ><span data-bind="text: Title"></span></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>

 </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

I get an alert with [![alert][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

Try it as below:

The javascript code:

```
var results = [];

function LoadStuff() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://demo/Dev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('news')/items",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"}, 
      success: function(data){
        results.push.apply(results, data.d.results);
        ko.applyBindings(results);
      },
      error: function (fn, status, error) {
        console.log('Error:' + error);
      } 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    LoadStuff();
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<div>
    <div data-bind="template:{name:'KoList', foreach:results, as:'rows'}"></div>
        <script type="text/html" id="KoList">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="knockOutTable">
            <tr>
             <td data-bind="text:Title"></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </script>
</div>
```

Reference - [Getting started with REST in SharePoint 2013](https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/tag/knockout/)

Comment: Not working.I dont get any errors but I don't see the items.

Comment: Edited the code, can you check ?